# RemoteApps for non-domain clients

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remoteapp

I would like to have a Remote Desktop farm's RemoteApps silently added to the *RemoteApp and Desktop Connections* control panel of Windows 7 machines.

The general procedure of [subscribing to an RSS feed served by the RD Web Access server via `rundll32 tsworkspace`](http://stealthpuppy.com/deploy-remoteapp-programs-start-menu-silently/) seems to be the way to go, but the ***clients in question are in a separate, non-trusting domain than the RD farm***. And the `https://rdbroker/RDWeb/FeedLogin/WebFeedlogin.aspx` URI requires authentication, so it simply does not work.

I have tried enabling Anonymous Authentication (using *IUSR*, *Application pool identity* or even a privileged domain user as the identity) for the `RDWeb/FeedLogin` folder in IIS' site tree, but an attempt to retreive the feed returns `Server Error in '/RDWeb/FeedLogin' Application.` IIS logs an unhandled NullReference exception:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 26.05.2014 14:50:08 
Event time (UTC): 26.05.2014 12:50:08 
Event ID: 66cc347cf8884a4fa0567b5e7c378d61 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/RDWeb/FeedLogin-6-130455822088289842 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /RDWeb/FeedLogin 
    Application Path: C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb\FeedLogin\ 
    Machine name: rdbroker 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 1016 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\RDWebAccess 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://rdbroker:443/RDWeb/FeedLogin/WebFeedlogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=An unhandled exception has occurred.fRDWebAn unhandled exception has occurred.fFeedAn unhandled exception has occurred.fwebfeed.aspx 
    Request path: /RDWeb/FeedLogin/WebFeedlogin.aspx 
    User host address: 192.168.8.70 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\RDWebAccess 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 6 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\RDWebAccess 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at ASP.webfeedlogin_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally "solved" this by automating the tsworkspace dialogs using an [AutoITv3](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) script. I have populated the *employeeID* attributes with the users' RemoteApp usernames and made the script query this attribute, using it to pre-fill the security dialog for the RemoteApp web feed as well as the *UsernameHint* registry values for the RD client itself. So in the best case the user would just need to run the executable and enter her password into an authentication dialog pre-filled with her user name.

The script is below. Please note that the *WinWait* calls are waiting for windows with specific titles or message texts to appear, you will want to change this according to your clients' localization and Windows version.

```
#include <AD.au3>

Dim $WCXPath = "\\fserver2\RemoteAppFeed$\rdcb.wcx"
Dim $FeedAddress = "rdcb.ad.contoso.com"
Dim $WizardWinHandle
Dim $SecurityWinHandle
Dim $CallResult
Dim $aProperties[1][2]
Dim $UserName

$UserName="AD\<YourADLogin>"

; Open Connection to the Active Directory
_AD_Open()

; Write UsernameHint values with the user's RD server authentication name
$aProperties = _AD_GetObjectProperties(@UserName, "employeeID")
;_ArrayDisplay($aProperties, "Active Directory Functions - Example 2 - Properties for user '" & @UserName & "'")
If IsArray($aProperties) Then
   If UBound($aProperties,2)=2 and UBound($aProperties,1)=2 Then
      If $aProperties[1][0]="employeeID" and StringLen($aProperties[1][1])>1 Then
         $UserName = "CIT-AD\" & $aProperties[1][1]
         RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers\rdfarm.ad.contoso.com", "UsernameHint", "REG_SZ", $UserName)
         RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers\ts13.ad.contoso.com", "UsernameHint", "REG_SZ", $UserName)
      EndIf
   EndIf
EndIf

Run ("C:\Windows\System32\xwizard.exe RunWizard /u {7940acf8-60ba-4213-a7c3-f3b400ee266d} /z" & $WCXPath)
$WizardWinHandle = WinWait("Neue Verbindung mit RemoteApp", $FeedAddress)
;MsgBox(0, "Debug", "RemoteApp Window appeared with handle " & $WizardWinHandle)
WinActivate($WizardWinHandle)
$CallResult = ControlClick($WizardWinHandle, "", "Button1")
;MsgBox(0, "Debug", "Clicked "Next" with result" & $CallResult)
$SecurityWinHandle = WinWait("Windows-Sicherheit")
;MsgBox(0, "Debug", "Windows Security Window appeared with handle " & $SecurityWinHandle)
WinActivate($SecurityWinHandle)
$CallResult = ControlSend($SecurityWinHandle, "", "Edit1", $UserName)
;MsgBox(0, "Debug", "Sent username data with result" & $CallResult)
$CallResult = ControlClick($SecurityWinHandle, "", "Button1")
;MsgBox(0, "Debug", "Clicked to remember credentials with result" & $CallResult)
$CallResult = ControlFocus($SecurityWinHandle, "", "Edit2")
;MsgBox(0, "Debug", "Focused password field with result" & $CallResult)
```